# node.js using callback on class functions

Tags: node.js

I want to return value to varibales  so I tried to write it like that using return but that did't work

```
class move {
    getLastMove(id){


        var MoveRequest = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id";

        var query = connection.query(MoveRequest, function(err,rows, result) {
        //console.log('rows', rows.length);
        if (rows.length == 0) { // evaluate the count
            return ("rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1");
        }
        if (rows.length > 0) {
            for (var i in rows) {


                console.log('getLastMove',id);
                var move = rows[i].MoveString; 
                if (rows[i].GameId == id){

                    return move;
                }

            }
        }



        //console.log("Total Records:- " + result[0].total);

        });


            var move="rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1";
            return move;


    }


};
```

so I tried to use callback like that

```
class move {

        getLastMove(id){


            var MoveRequest = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id";

            var query = connection.query(MoveRequest, function(err,rows, result,callback) {
            //console.log('rows', rows.length);
            if (rows.length == 0) { // evaluate the count
                callback ("rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1");
            }
            if (rows.length > 0) {
                for (var i in rows) {


                    console.log('getLastMove',id);
                    var move = rows[i].MoveString; 
                    if (rows[i].GameId == id){

                        callback(move);
                    }

                }
            }



            //console.log("Total Records:- " + result[0].total);

            });


                var move="rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1";
                callback(move);


        }


    };
```

but when run callback example i get this error

> TypeError: callback is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using callback in a wrong way. Pass a callback to getLastMove() :

```
class move {
getLastMove(id, callback){
    var MoveRequest = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id";

    var query = connection.query(MoveRequest, function(err,rows, result) {
        if(err) {
            return callback(err)
        }

        if (rows.length == 0) { // evaluate the count
            return callback (null, "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1");
        }
        if (rows.length > 0) {
            for (var i in rows) {
                if (rows[i].GameId == id){
                    callback(null, rows[i].MoveString);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

};

Suppose `moveObj` is an object of type `move`, call the function `getLastMove` like:

```
var moveObj = new move();
moveObj.getLastMove(34, function (err, data) { // 34 is the value of `id`
    if(err) {
        // There was some error in execution of getLastMove; var `err` has info regarading that. 
        return console.log("There was some err while executing getLastMove", err);
    }

    // If no Error, process your `data` accordingly
    console.log("Data returned by callback", data);
});
```

Comment: i still get the same line after editing here     return callback(null,rows[i].MoveString);

Comment: cant i just write this part like that    var move = rows[i].MoveString; 
   if (rows[i].GameId == id){
     
    return callback(null,move);
   }

Comment: i tried to write it with out return like that and the error stil exist callback(null,rows[i].MoveString);

Comment: @darknight Use the callback correctly. See the edited answer. If you don't know much about callbacks, have a look at https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks/ . And read about it from other sources too.

Answer (score 2):

```
    class move {

        getLastMove(id,callback){
            var query = connection.query(MoveRequest, function(err,rows, result) {
                //do some operation then
                 if (rows.length > 0) {
                    for (var i in rows) {
                        console.log('getLastMove',id);
                        var move = rows[i].MoveString; 
                        if (rows[i].GameId == id){
                            callback(err,move) //<-------
                        }
                   }
                }

           });
        }                
    };

var moveInstance = new move();

moveInstance.getLastMove(id,function(err,result){ //code here })
```

Comment: can you give me example explain more  how i can callback var move ?

Comment: i still get the error my last edit getLastMove(id,callback){
 var MoveRequest = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id";
 var query = connection.query(MoveRequest, function(err,rows, result) {
 if (rows.length == 0) { 
  callback(err,"rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1");
 }
    if (rows.length > 0) {
  for (var i in rows) {
   var move = rows[i].MoveString; 
   if (rows[i].GameId == id){    
    callback(err,move);
   }
    
  }
    }     
 });
  var move="rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1";
  callback(err,move);
}

Comment: what is the error? and what are these two lines for? "var move = "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1";
    callback(err, move);" below query.with those lines you are sending callback twice